# Google datastore transaction when no entity group

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I have a KIND made up of USERS:

```
USER
    username<Key,String>
    friends <array of strings>
```

Two users can be friends (user can have many friends). If a users are friends both of their usernames are inside of each others 'friends' property. So if they become friends, I need to insert each usernames into the two entities and guarantee that they were both inserted and if there was an error or something it should be rolled back (All or nothing operation). Reading about transactions inside of Google Datastore from my understanding transactions can only be done within entitiy groups. Since these are two USER entities there is no parent/child relationship between them two, they are both root entities. What would be the best method to guarntee this operation goes through. The same would apply if a user was deleted, I would then need to delete that user from all the fiends properties of all the users who were friends with the deleted user and I must guarantee this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datastore supports transactions involving [multiple entity groups](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/#Python_Cross_group_transactions).

Comment: Perfect, that makes the modelling for me much easier! Thanks for the link!

Comment: Thought there is a limit to the number of entities in XG transactions. If you have a 100 friends it's not possible to wrap that number of entities in the single transaction.  In this scenario you would need to model a seperate controlling activity that manages a series of transactional deletes, with a roll forward model. Running this is a retryable task that tracks where it is up to, and any retry will eventually cleanup (delete) all friend references.

Comment: @TimHoffman - Every "friendship" requires update of two entities only.

Comment: Ok, your limiting the friends to a single list of keys, which sets the upper bounds of the number of friends someone can have. I missed that in your doc.  I was thinking of larger possible scaling.

Comment: I also think this is not the optimal model. In addition to the upper limit on friends, it is also expensive - every new friendship requires update of two User entities, which may incur significant write costs, especially if User entity has indexed properties.